# Android NDK link to static library

Tags: android-ndk

**undefined reference to `get_int()'**

I'm trying to build shared library in android.
This library uses functions from prebuilt static library "libATest.a"
I have tried all the methods I can use. Always got the error "undefined reference to `get_int()'",but i have define it in libAtest.a. Call for help!
**Android ndk r8**

[image]

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ATest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libATest.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := capi
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := capi.cpp

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := ATest
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
#LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

atest.h:

```
int get_int();
```

Application.mk:

```
APP_MODULES :=capi
```

capi.cpp:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#include "atest.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

jstring Java_com_wzh_test_AndriodJNITestActivity_ttstest(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz){
    get_int();
    return env->NewStringUTF("I'm from C!");
}


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

libATest.a:

```
#include "atest.h"
int get_int(){
    return 55;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `get_int` in an `extern "C"` block too, or it will be treated as having C++ linkage.

You can tell that it is being treated as a C++ function because the linker error mentions the function signature (`get_int()` as opposed to `get_int`).

EDIT:
Your second problem is that you called your library source file `libATest.a`! Static libraries have to be compiled. Instead, you should have a file `atest.c` containing the source code (the `get_int` function), and use `LOCAL_SRC_FILES := atest.c` when building the `ATest` library. You will also want to delete `libATest.a` to avoid any dependency issues.

Comment: After I added the extern "C" to .h and .a file,getting the error"undefined reference to `get_int'".GOD!Help!

Comment: Unfortunately,I hava to use libATest.a,which is provided by other company and I can't get the source code.Now I'm doing a test ,so I just build a simply static library named "libATest.a".

Comment: What I'm telling you is that you aren't correctly building *your* static library.